# Boiling water to kill weeds?

Tags: weed-control, weeds, crabgrass

Last summer I found that boiling water will kill weeds, and kills them quick.  However boiling water takes time and a large individual crabgrass would take a whole pot of boiling water to kill the weed.  My question asks if anyone knows of any other home remedies for weeds.  Spot treatment for crabgrass is all I need.  Small yard.

Comment: Home remedies? Is there a reason you don't want to use a weed killer? You could always use your hands. It's honestly the most effective and innocuous method of permanently removing weeds that I have ever found.

Comment: I don't like putting chemicals in my yard.  Some weeds get the hand but not crabgrass not here in Fort Worth.  Within a week of it first sprouting it's next to impossible to get out with by hand in this clay soil.  I really like the boiling water killing it on contract and was looking for something similar

Comment: You might try household vinegar.

Comment: You'll likely be advised to try vinegar or salt - this on using vinegar https://www.gardenmyths.com/vinegar-weed-killer-myth/ is worth reading - salt will unfortunately make the soil toxic and kill nearby plants too. I think you're stuck with boiling water, frankly, if you can't dig it out.

Comment: @Bryan Hearn I would suggest you get the ground wet before you try to pull out the crab grass. Should come out no problem if the soil is wet in that area.

Comment: Much less  work and energy for the same affect  would be use of a propane burner. Depending on economics flame weeding is done in agriculture

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to kill the weeds as is, you could think of them as future fertilizer. Get some cardboard or newspaper, lay it on top, and start "lasagna gardening" by putting compost on top of that. You'll be able to plant in it come spring. One thing I've learned from weeds is that you can try to go down to their level, but you end up opening up the soil for weed seeds that are embedded in the ground.

Dealing with problems can be that way in life. You can choose to dwell on the problem or see it as a path to build something preferable. BTW, since the cardboard will suppress weeds below it, the new weeds sprouting in your garden will be easier to pull!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boil water for nearly free you can get a solar  cooker that does this. And then get free hot water that you can use to keep killing those unwanted plants forever.

A small hand held butane torch might also work but the weeds grow up again.